# adding a foreign key in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, key

I am using the following  command to add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE Company
ADD FOREIGN KEY (enumber)
REFERENCES emp(enumber);
```

... but it's giving an error:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Foreign key 'company_enumber_FK' references invalid column 'enumber' in referencing table 'company'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Now if I create a column `enumber` in table `company` and execute it the command runs but shows null value.

Here `enumber` is a primary key of table `emp` and `company` is another table in which I want the foreign key `enumber` to be added

What should I do?

Comment: "the command runs but shows null" - Were you expecting the system to somehow, magically, know what the correct value to populate into `enumber` was when the column was added?

Comment: As far as i know foreign key value should not be null . so why is it showing null?

Comment: But again - how do you expect the system to know what non-NULL value it's meant to populate? And you're incorrect, it's fine for a foreign key reference to be null.

Comment: System fills null when the no of rows of child and parent table is different as in this case.Am i correct?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what your understanding of foreign keys is - I can't make much sense of what you're now asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach would be to add the new column to the `Company` table - either as a nullable column or (if all rows should receive the same value) with a default.

Next, you apply the foreign key constraint.

If, in the first paragraph, you opted for the nullable column, you should now write an `UPDATE` that determines what the correct value is for each row in `Company`.

Finally, you can alter `Company` again to change the nullable column to be `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This means the `Company` doesn't have a field named `enumber`. So in other words, this:

```
ADD FOREIGN KEY (enumber)
```

is referencing the wrong field in `Company`.

Comment: Now if i create a column enumber in table company and execute it the command runs but shows null value. Why is it so?

Comment: @sugam, what do you mean *shows `null` value*? I'm really not following you there.

Comment: @sugam, if you're saying that a foreign key field can't contain `null` - that's an incorrect assumption. A foreign field key can't contain a value that **doesn't exist** in the keyed table. If you want to ensure all records have a value - set the field to non-nullable. Bear in mind you'll need to **UPDATE** all records first because they will need a value.

Comment: System fills null when the no of rows of child and parent table is different as in this case.Am i correct? –